# Price is automatically rewritten to 0.00 on the product detail page for Magento 2.4.3-p1

Tags: price, upgrade, installation, composer, catalog-price-rules

Price is overwritten in the product detail page to 0.00 for non-English/United States locale options.

I tried to find a solution to solve this problem but found nothing on the forum. There are several discussions but no real solution that works. It's really annoying because I can't move forward in my project. I'm stuck with this problem. I would like to know if other people who have encountered the same problem have found a solution? I will try to give you as much information as possible so that you can reproduce the case and see how it goes.

I am using version 2.4.3-p1
I have managed cloud hosting.

I have installed magento with SSH commands.
`composer2 create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition /home/clients/.../sites/my_project/`

`user:` ****

`pasword:` *****

> /home/clients/.../sites/my_project/bin/magento setup:install
> --base-url=http://my_project/
> --db-host=localhost 
> --db-name=base1 
> --db-user=user1 
> --db-password=***** 
> --admin-firstname=admin 
> --admin-lastname=gintoki
> --admin-email=admin@admin.ch
> --admin-user=sinpachi 
> --admin-password=**** 
> --language=fr_FR 
> --currency=CHF 
> --timezone=Europe/Zurich 
> --use-rewrites=1

during the installation a message caught my eye:

> Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewriteGraphQl': Module
> 'Magento_CompareListGraphQl': Module
> 'Magento_ComposerRootUpdatePlugin': Running data recurring...**Web
> Setup Wizard installation of "magento/composer-root-update-plugin"
> failed; unable to load /home/clients/..../composer.json.**
>
> Module 'Magento_User': Magento_Payment' module: Module
> 'Magento_Sales':

I get the same message when I try to update
`/home/clients/.../sites/my_project/bin/magento setup:upgrade`

when I try to update the composer I get

> ~$ composer2 update Composer could not find a composer.json file in
> /home/clients/ee24eb9be927c7947ffd34f7e06c2e2e To initialize a
> project, please create a composer.json file as described in the
> https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

I don't know if all these problems are related to each other.

Some help would be really welcome. If someone has a solution or ideas about the origin of the problem.

Thanks to all! :)

Comment: the problem with the composer was solved

Answer (score 0):

the problem with the composer was solved

all the part bellow are ok now :

(..) Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewriteGraphQl': Module 'Magento_CompareListGraphQl': Module 'Magento_ComposerRootUpdatePlugin': Running data recurring...Web Setup Wizard installation of "magento/composer-root-update-plugin" failed; unable to load /home/clients/..../composer.json.

Module 'Magento_User': Magento_Payment' module: Module 'Magento_Sales': (..)

I get the same message when I try to update /home/clients/.../sites/my_project/bin/magento setup:upgrade

when I try to update the composer I get ~$ composer2 update Composer could not find a composer.json file in /home/clients/ee24eb9be927c7947ffd34f7e06c2e2e To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

but i have still the price problem, the price is overwritten in the product detail page to 0.00 for non english/United States locale options.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below commit.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/ae304d43cd36322b1ff8145d70c9b2e9aeb0cdef
which can solve the issue.